# What is wrong in this rdlc expression. When ever the difference is zero it throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc, ssrs-2008-r2, dynamic-rdlc-generation

```
=iif(Sum(Fields!ClsRead.Value)-Sum(Fields!OpnRead.Value)=0,"NO HSD Supplied",sum(Fields!HSDIssued.Value)/(Sum(Fields!ClsRead.Value)-Sum(Fields!OpnRead.Value)))
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide more details about your issue? What's error message?

Comment: @MaciejLos  Hey, this expression is basically to calculate average petrol consumption. i am trying to write an expression when ever the difference between open reading and close reading is 0 it must return NO HSD SUPPLIED else if it not 0 then calculate average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `IIf` you have to remember that both side (`TruePart` and `FalsePart`) are always evaluated so dividing by 0 raise an `#Error`.

You can use [custom code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-code-to-a-report-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) (right click design surface outside report > `Report Properties > Code`) and replace `IIf` with an `If/Then/Else`.